# PHP Unit testing is not compatible with PHP8, does it support backward compatibility?

Tags: php, phpunit, php-8

I have several test units in PHPUnit and the PHPUnit is not compatible with php8. I`m looking for a way to run old tests on PHP8.
Is there any wrapper for PHPUnit to work with PHP8?

By the way, this is the error from the composer install:

```
    - phpunit/phpunit 9.1.1 requires php ^7.3 -> your PHP version (8.0.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

It may work by removing the requirement from the PHPUnit composer file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PHPUnit supports PHP 8.0 starting from version 9.3.0. Just upgrade PHPUnit to last version to run your tests.

Comment: Thanks, I remove composer.lock and install it again.

Comment: You may run `composer update`, too; that will rewrite the lockfile.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-9.html) it only supports 7.3 and 7.4. That's confusing and should be updated.

Comment: if anybody having problems: there's always the option to go back to 7.4 , install something, then go up to 8.0 and see what's happening

Comment: It's still showing only 7.3 or 7.4 in the docs